# Display or Hide rows based on Boolean Selection

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder, rdl

I am having trouble in showing the data I need to show depending on whether I select True or False option.

If I choose True for the 'Anuncios Adjudicados' parameter (from spanish to english it says 'Adjudicated Ads'), I want to show only the rows that have values different than 0€ and If  I choose False, I want to show ALL and EVERYTHING (zero values and non-zero values).

Now I can filter the data to show only the non-zero values when i choose the True option, but when I choose the False, it only shows the zero values..

﻿My parameter is created as the following:
[boolean parameter creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwqHQ.png)

My dataset properties has the folowing query:

```
select Adjudicado = IIF(fa.[Num_Adjudicados] = 1, 'Adjudicado', 'No Adjudicado'), fa.Val_Persupuesto as [Valor Presupuesto] from [dbo].[F_Anuncio] fa where fa.Num_Adjudicados = @AnunciosAdjudicados
```

and the following image shows what happens if i choose false:

[It should show these rows as well as rows with non-zero values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA3Qm.png)

Help

Answer (score 1):

1. Alright Let your Dataset Comes All Values i.e EVERYTHING(0 and non
   zero)
2. Now Add Row Visibility Filter

   [image: List item]

[image]

3. Now Add Expression like below

   =IIF(Fields!AdjudicatedAds = true And Fields!YourCostField.Value = 0,True,False)
4. Above Expression Hides all Records where AdjudicatedAds = true And Fields!YourCostField.Value = 0

Comment: Hi AnkUser, My AdjudicatedAds is a parameter, not a field. I tried to do the same using "Parameters!AdjudicatedAds = true" but when I write Fields!YourCostField.Value = 0, there is an error with this sintax, I don't understand why.

Comment: can you not add AdjudicatedAds  as field in your DataSet, I mean like AccountNR or AccountID something so that every row has AdjudicatedAds  with it's value